# Query on ActiveModel rails for numrange postgresql column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, range

Want to write this  in rails code using model methods to search if given values lies in the range stored in numrange column
Example: 500 is included in range value [100,1000]

Tried using

> **PricingInfo.where(id:  params[:id], denomination:
> params[:denomination].. params[:denomination])**

- PricingInfo is model name
- denomination is of numrange datatype

which queries

> SELECT "pricing_infos".* FROM "pricing_infos" WHERE
> "pricing_infos"."id" = "1" AND "pricing_infos"."denomination" =
> "[300.0,300.0]"

I want it to query

> SELECT * from  pricing_infos  where id = '1' AND
> denomination::numrange @> 1000.0;

Answer (score 0):

Normally querying by id will return a single result, or none. So I'm not sure why you include id as a condition. But since you have asked. This is how you query a `numrange` data field:

```rb
PricingInfo.where(id: 1).where("denomination::numrange  @> ?",1000.00)
```